# How to force Spring kafka Binder to start consuming from topic

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I have a Spring project using a kafka binder with annotated streamlistener for a topic.

The consumer is in a group and when I start the service the consumer just sits and does nothing except that zookeeper says syncConnected

I used kafka-consumer-groups to extract this information:

```
GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
logging-service-group          BiddingServiceBean             0          0               42              42              consumer-2_/0.0.0.0(fakeip)
```

How do I force consumption?

Comment: Perhaps your listener thread is stuck in your code someplace? Turning on debug logging for `org.springframework` and `org.apache.kafka` as well as taking a thread dump should point you to the problem.

Comment: It's solved. Thanks for your help. You are right. There was an error in the code and it didn't appear in the log and I have set autoCommitOnError = false